# Bayesian improper prior for discrete data

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

There is one remark in my lecture notes:
if $X$ (data) is a discrete distribution then one cannot use an improper prior.

Can anyone prove it?

Comment: What's discrete, the data or the parameter you're finding the posterior of? If you have discrete data, this isn't true in general, for example if you a binomial likelihood, $y|n,p\sim\textsf{Bin}(n,p)$, and you place an improper $\textsf{Beta}(0,0)$ prior on $p$, as long as $y$ isn't $0$ or $n$, the posterior is proper.

Comment: @marmle: your example does not work since one cannot choose a prior depending on the observation value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for not being able to use an improper prior in the case of a finite distribution is that, if the distribution $p_\theta$ of $X$ has support in $\{a_1,\ldots,a_N\}$, then the posterior$$\pi(\theta|x)=\pi(\theta)p_\theta(x)\big/ m(x)$$is not defined as
$$m(x)=\int p_\theta(x)\pi(\theta)\text{d}\theta$$cannot be finite for all $x$'s in $\{a_1,\ldots,a_N\}$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N m(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N \int p_\theta(a_i)\pi(\theta)\text{d}\theta=\int\sum_{i=1}^Np_\theta(a_i)\pi(\theta)\text{d}\theta=\infty$$implies that at least one of the $m(a_i)$'s is infinite, hence that the posterior(s) do(es) not exist for the corresponding $i$'s.

The argument does not extend to the infinitely countable case though: take for instance a Poisson $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ distribution and an improper prior $\pi(\lambda)=1/\sqrt\lambda$. Then$$\pi(\lambda|x)\propto \lambda^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\{-\lambda\}$$is well-defined as a Gamma$(x+\frac{1}{2},1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!Just to make sure, what you are saying is that we can't use any improper prior only when the data have a finite distribution (instead of a discrete distribution) , is that correct?

Comment: @ChengyuOuyang: yes, you are prohibited from using an improper prior when the data takes a finite number of possible values. Else, some if not all improper priors are valid to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just a pointer about the $Beta(0,0)$ prior. If $X\sim Binomial(n,p)$, with $n\geq 2$ fixed, then the $Beta(0,0)$ prior for $p$, pointed out by @marmle and which is independent of the sample (opposite to what @Xi'an says), leads to a proper posterior distribution only if $y\neq 0, n$. That is, this is an improper prior that leads to a proper posterior distribution under some conditions.

This prior is often used in practice since the posterior mean coincides with the MLE. Also, in practice, people tend to prefer a $Beta(\epsilon,\epsilon)$ prior, with $\epsilon\approx 0$, in order to obtain a posterior where the posterior mean (which is most often reported) is close to the MLE, while avoiding problems of impropriety of the posterior when $y=0,n$.

Comment: Merry christmas!And thank you for pointing out.By the way, we take integral of the posterior to see if it’s improper, is that right?How do we find out it is improper at y=0 or y=n at the first place,just by looking at the posterior distribution?It is not very intuitive for me.

Comment: @ChengyuOuyang The posterior distribution in this case is a beta since the beta prior is [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions). In order for it to be a proper distribution, it is required that both parameters are positive, which only happens when $y\neq 0,n$ (see the expression of the beta-binomial model). Merry Xmas.

Comment: This isn't the opposite of xi'an said. He was a bit unclear but if you read his answer carefully you'll see that he says that an improper prior leads to an improper posterior for _some_ possible observed data ("the posterior(s) do(es) not exist for the corresponding $i$'s.") In your example those possible observed data are (as you note) $y=0$ and $y=n$.